# Energy gap in Parent hamiltonian of MPS

Tags: condensed-matter, ground-state, spin-chains, tensor-network

Given a block injective [matrix product state](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_product_state) (MPS) with D blocks, how does the energy gap of corresponding parent hamiltonian scale with D? And is there a good reference which gives an analysis of this?
Thanks.

Comment: What is an MPS? What does it mean to be block injective? SE questions should be accessible for people other than those who already know what the question is about!

Comment: @ACuriousMind ... though this might pose a fairly general problem with research-level questions.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch: Yeah, I'm not saying you should write a complete exposition into the topic you're asking about, but at least the explanation of acronyms or some explanatory links under the relevant concepts aren't too much to ask, I think.

Comment: @ACuriousMind Fully agreed! Guess it depends what you consider "accessible" ;-)

Comment: Thanks all for your comments and edit. I ll take care of clearer explanations in questions next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gap of the parent Hamiltonian does not depend on the number $D$ of blocks (at least not directly). The spectral gap of the parent Hamiltonian in the block-injective case is analyzed and a lower bound is given in B. Nachtergaele, [Commun. Math. Phys. 175, 565 (1996)](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02099509), [arXiv:cond-mat/9410110](http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/9410110).